# NSOperationQueue is crashing in IOS

Tags: nsoperationqueue

I have a project which downloads images in background using `NSOperationQueue`. It was working until now on devices with IOS 4.3. However if I build the app with base sdk 4.3 or with 5 and run the app on device with IOS5, the app crashes. When app is launched, it adds `NSOperation` objects into queue for downloading the images. If in between I press back button, I cancel the `NSOperation` and it crashes and displays following trace on console:

```
#0  0x004727b7 in ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_0 ()
#1  0x026a5618 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#2  0x026a7a10 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#3  0x974bb781 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#4  0x974bb5c6 in start_wqthread ()
```

and prints "ResourceLoadOperation isFinished = YES without being started by the queue it is in"
If I comment the cancel method call, app doesnot crash.
Is there any updates on the `NSOperation` changes for IOS5?

Comment: I have the same problem. Commenting the release of the NSOperation object makes the trick, as you said, but I am not very sure that memory management is right in this case...

Comment: Yes just commenting the cancel method may not be right in terms of memory management. But is that a problem of the processing speed in ios 5 that is causing this issue since the same works fine on IOS 4.3 devices?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this same problem when building against iOS 5. I ended up creating a flag named `operationStarted` that was `NO` by default and I toggled to `YES` when the `start` method was called. Then in my `finish` method (where I generate the KVO notifications), I checked the value of the flag before firing the notifications.

The flag definition looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isOperationStarted) BOOL operationStarted;
```

The `start` method:

```
- (void)start {
    [self setOperationStarted:YES];
    ...
}
```

My `finish` method which is called when the operation is complete or cancelled:

```
- (void)finish {    
    if (![self isOperationStarted]) return;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    executing = NO;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    finished = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

That ended up resolving the issue for me. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: i'm curious why do you even need operationStarted property when you already have isexecuting for the very same purpose?